# Magento: show shipping price checkout including tax

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

We have a problem with the tax settings in Magento for the shipping method. If we are correct we have everything set up right. We want 21% of tax to the shipping methods and this is set up correct. In the image below you will see in the the totals a shipping amount of 3.95 euro and this is correct. In red you will only see that the shipping amount at the part of "verzendwijzen" shows 3.26, so without tax.

Does anyone know how to change this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Admin panel, select System > Configuration.

In the Configuration panel on the left, under Sales, select Tax

Click to expand the calculation settings, and in the dropdown of shipping prices select Including Tax.

Also on the same page expand price display setting.

In display shipping Prices select including tax.

Hope these will do the thing if you haven't changed and core file of magento

Comment: Everything was correct except the "In display shipping Prices select including tax." Thanks

Comment: glad i can help, actually i provided both things that arrive in my mind, for the solution